# Android App to IOs porting?

Tags: android, ios, converters

I have currently developed on android and i would like to convert to IOs. Is there any converter to do this?? any suggestions welcomed.
The android app uses rss feeds, json reader, google api. I will need every aspect to be converted as im not versed in objective C??
Please Help

Comment: You should google it first..there is no such way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are cross platform frameworks for developing once and running on both Android and iOS.

Some examples are [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/), [Corona](http://www.coronalabs.com/), [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html) & [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/).

Or [Unity](http://www.unity3d.com/) and [Libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) specialized for game development.

However there is no way to fully convert an app you have already developed with Android SDK to an iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

No mate there is no easy way to do this. You better follow some tutorials on iOS developing and go through this process. It won't be so hard to you because you already have a programming background.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, im screwed lol

Comment: here are some good tutorials on iOS developing. http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: @PropK I agree, you are screwed.